# Return another Object with SpringData

Tags: spring-data-jpa

How can I perform a JPA query for another object?

in the normal case we do :

```
public interface Object1Repository extends JpaRepository<Object1, Long> { public List<Object2> findById(Long id);
 }
```

but here i want to do the samething with another object (object2) :

```
 public interface Object1Repository extends JpaRepository<Object1, Long> { 
public List<Object2> findById(Long id); }
```

Comment: add more details to your question.

Comment: Please edit your question with the extra details. The comment cannot display code in a useful form.

Comment: Trying to merge comment and question.

Comment: @BobDalgleish its done

Comment: Just put the query in a `@Query` annotation or create a separate repository for `Object2`. It is hard to tell which might be the "right" way to do it without more context information about the classes involved.